# Reflecting an image

Tags: java, image, image-processing

This is part of a project for my computer science class. One of the tasks is to take an image and reflect it. I've already initialized a picture called image. When I run this method, instead of reflecting the picture it mirrors it.

```
public void reflect()
{
    //Creating a for loop to get all of the x values for the image object
    for(int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++)
    {
        //Creating a nested for loop to get all of the y values for each x value
        for(int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++)
        {
            //Getting a pixel object for the given x and y value
            Pixel pixelObj = image.getPixel(x, y);
            //I'm pretty sure this next line is where I'm screwing up.
            //It's probably really simple, but I can't figure it out. 
            Pixel newPixel = image.getPixel(image.getWidth()-x-1, y);
            //This sets the color values of the new pixel to the ones of the old pixel
            newPixel.setRed(pixel0bj.getRed());
            newPixel.setGreen(pixel0bj.getGreen());
            newPixel.setBlue(pixel0bj.getBlue());
        }
    }
    image.show();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Make sure to always ask a question.  I don't see any question marks.  Also, make sure you tag your question properly; What language is this?

Comment: Reflection of an image is not its mirror? Or you mean it's a mirror on the wrong axis?

Comment: Sorry. The language is Java. The question is how can I make it reflect and not mirror? What I mean by that I want to flip the image, versus having the first half of the image and then the same first half of the image is on the axis. So if you had an image of the letter C, reflecting would turn it into a backwards C, but mirroring it would make an O.

Comment: try this one http://mrbool.com/how-to-display-flip-and-provide-a-reflection-to-the-image-with-java/25983

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to swap the corresponding pixel values. Currently, you are overwriting the right half of the image before saving their pixel values in a reference for putting them to the left half.

Below I've illustrated what I mean by "swapping" value instead of just assigning them uni-directionally:

```
//Getting a pixel object for the given x and y value
Pixel pixelObj = image.getPixel(x, y);
Pixel oppositePixel = image.getPixel(image.getWidth()-x-1, y);
//Store the RGB values of the opposite pixel temporarily
int redValue = oppositePixel.getRed();
int greenValue = oppositePixel.getGreen();
int blueValue = oppositePixel.getBlue();
//This swaps the color values of the new pixel to the ones of the old pixel
oppositePixel.setRed(pixel0bj.getRed());
oppositePixel.setGreen(pixel0bj.getGreen());
oppositePixel.setBlue(pixel0bj.getBlue());
pixelObj.setRed(redValue);
pixelObj.setGreen(greenValue);
pixelObj.setBlue(blueValue);
```

If you swap pixels both ways in each round, it's sufficient to loop from `0` to `image.getWidth() / 2`.

Have a look how it's done in [ImageJ's `ImageProcessor` class](https://github.com/imagej/ImageJA/blob/master/src/main/java/ij/process/ImageProcessor.java#L1408-L1418) as a reference.

Another solution is to use a matrix transformation and scale by -1 in the x direction. See the ImageJ [`scale` op](https://github.com/imagej/imagej-ops/blob/master/src/main/java/net/imagej/ops/image/scale/ScaleImg.java) for a more elaborate example using the [ImgLib2 library](https://github.com/imglib/imglib2) for image processing in Java.

Comment: I changed it to image.getWidth()/2, but it still has the same problem. I didn't understand the two pieces of code you linked me to, I'm still very beginner. Can you be more specific about what I should change?

Comment: @Compton I edited my answer to illustrate what I mean by swapping.